# How to fix Gatsby query for Contentful reference types

Tags: graphql, gatsby, contentful

I'm getting my content from **Contentful**.
The structure is simple:

**Page**

```
- sections (ref)
-- Section1
--- modules (ref)
---- Module1
---- Module2
-- Section2
--- modules (ref)
---- Module1
---- Module2
```

I cannot seem to reach nested reference types.

My content model has a page that has a reference module modules that included a title and a list of other modules. Seems that content cannot be reached with the plugin. Do you know why? and how to fix it?

````
    allContentfulProductLandingPage{
        edges {
            node {
                name
                    sections { #this is a reference type
                        title
                        modules { #this is a reference type
                            __typename
                            #title #I need title and subfields here
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}```



How can I get more then the __typename from this query? Likethe title I commented out?
````

Answer (score 0):

You might have already figured this out, I ran into the same issue. The only way I could get it to work is if all the references were from the same content type. I couldn't mix and match them.